# Constructing a Borel-measurable function from a functional inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{X})$ and $(A, \mathcal{A})$ be [standard Borel spaces](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Standard_Borel_space), and let $q(\cdot | \cdot)$ be a substochastic kernel with source $(X\times A, \mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{A})$ and target $(X, \mathcal{X})$. The latter means $q: X \times A \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow [0,1]$ is such that (i) $(x,a) \mapsto q(B | x, a)$ is $(\mathcal{X}\otimes\mathcal{A})$-measurable for each $B \in \mathcal{X}$ and (ii) $B \mapsto q(B | x, a)$ is a sub-probability measure on $(X, \mathcal{X})$ for each $(x, a) \in X \times A$.

Suppose the bounded function $f: X \rightarrow [1, \infty)$ is *upper semi-analytic*, i.e. the set $\{x \in X: f(x) > \lambda\}$ is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) for every $\lambda \geq 0$, and satisfies

$$
f(x) \geq 1 + \int_X f(y)q(dy | x, a) \quad \text{for all} \ \ (x, a) \in X \times A. \qquad \text{(1)}
$$

**Question:** Does there also exist a bounded Borel-measurable function that satisfies (1)?

**Context:** This question came up in the context of Markov decision processes; see e.g. [this book](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/soc.html). There, $X$ is the set of states of a controlled random process, and $A$ is the set of available actions. If action $a$ is taken when the system is in state $x$, a reward is earned and the next state belongs to $B \in \mathcal{X}$ with probability $q(B | x, a)$ or the process terminates with probability $1-q(X | x, a)$.

Comment: I am not sure whether there always exists a Borel function satisfying a general inequality $f \geq Tf$, even if a semi-analytic solution does exist, hence the answer to your question depends a lot on $T$. In your case, I don't think this inequality has any solutions at all: essentially you are saying, that value of a function at every point is greater than 1 + some average value of the function, with averaging weights being point-dependent. Do you have any examples in mind?

Comment: You may be right about the non-existence of solutions in the case where $T$ is defined using a Markov kernel. I'm actually studying transient MDPs, namely those where the time to end up in a reward-free absorbing state is uniformly bounded. There (1) is satisfied when $f$ is the supremum over all policies of the process' lifetime, which is upper semi-analytic. I want a Borel function satisfying (1) because I want to use it to reduce the total-cost problem to a discounted MDP in the usual sense. Without additional assumptions, the resulting transition kernel is only analytically measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an integral inequality of the kind as in OP, the answer is yes at least in case whe there exists a probability measure $\mu$ such that $p(x,a) \ll \mu$ for all $x,a$. Then one can modify $f$ on a $\mu$-null set $N$ to make it Borel-measurable. Then the RHS does not change, and for all $x\notin N$ the inequality still holds. On $N$ we can define $f$ to be the RHS (yet again, it does not change the RHS), which is a Borel function due to the fact that $f$ and $p$ are Borel.

Comment: Good point! I've seen this kind of assumption in the literature, though I'm not sure how restrictive it is.